# meteor:How do I iterate over an array of objects when property name is not known

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I have an array of objects over which I have to iterate, but I don't know the property name of object.

```
{{# each }}
```

{{??}}
{{/each}}

Comment: Why don't you know the name of the keys in the object?

Comment: I guess you at least know where do you get it from?

Comment: @Sean My keys are being generated dynamically.

Comment: @RamilMuratov:Yes, I know the collecting i am getting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down into two `#each`s. The outer #each loops over the array of objects. The inner #each calls a template helper that returns an array of objects with label and value of each property of that object.

The template:

```
{{#each arrayOfObjects}}
  {{#each getAllFields}}
     <div class="item">
        {{this.label}} <span class="field-value">{{this.value}}</span>
     </div>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The helper:

```
getAllFields: function() {
    let fields = [];
    const unknownObject = this;

    _.each(Object.keys(unknownObject), function(theKey) {
        fields.push({label: theKey, value: unknownObject[theKey] });
    });

    fields = _.sortBy(fields, 'label');
    return fields;
}
```